# Does javac perform any bytecode level optimizations depending on the underlying operating system?

Tags: java, performance, javac

My understanding is that the Java bytecode produced by invoking `javac` is independent of the underlying operating system, but the HotSpot compiler will perform platform-specific JIT optimizations and compilations as the program is running.

However, I compiled code on Windows under a 32 bit JDK and executed it on Solaris under a 32 bit JVM (neither OS is a 64 bit operating system). The Solaris x86 box, to the best of my knowledge (working to confirm the specs on it) should outperform the Windows box in all regards (number of cores, amount of RAM, hard disk latency, processor speed, and so on). However, the same code is running measurably faster on Windows (a single data point would be a 7.5 second operation on Windows taking over 10 seconds on Solaris) on a consistent basis. My next test would be to compile on Solaris and note performance differences, but that just doesn't make sense to me, and I couldn't find any Oracle documentation that would explain what I'm seeing.

Given the same version (major, minor, release, etc.) of the JVM on two different operating systems, would invoking `javac` on the same source files result in different optimizations within the Java bytecode (the `.class` files produced)? Is there any documentation that explains this behavior?

Comment: I would say your Windows VM is better optimized. Compile the code on Solaris and compare the javac outputs, though.

Answer (score 3):

No. `javac` does not do any optimizations on different platforms.

See the oracle ["tools"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/tools.html) page (where `javac` and other tools are described):

> Each of the development tools comes in a Microsoft Windows version (Windows) and a Solaris or Linux version. **There is virtually no difference in features between versions.** However, there are minor differences in configuration and usage to accommodate the special requirements of each operating system. (*For example, the way you specify directory separators depends on the OS.*)

---

(Maybe the Solaris JVM is slower than the windows JVM?)

Comment: Is there any documentation that says this? I would like some kind of Oracle documentation to say that location of compilation has no effect. I haven't been able to find it, but I would expect that there are differences in the native implementation or the system isn't as powerful as I was led to believe.

Comment: Added some more information... (I actually edited the question during your comment :) )

Comment: I came across that, but features means capabilities, not necessarily how those are performed. Just because I can compile doesn't mean that compilation isn't different. I need to crunch some of these performance numbers before a meeting, so I can't rebuild and rerun tests before then. What would best answer my question (and it doesn't look like it exists) is a formal spec that says that javac behaves identically across all implementations of the Oracle javac tool, regardless of OS.

Comment: @Thomas Owens there's only one implementation per release. The byte code *of the compiler* is the same on Windows, Solaris, etc. So how can it possibly do different things? The byte code it produces for your code is the same too, modulo timestamps, you can verify that easily enough.

Comment: @EJP Documentation? I suspect that is true (as per my original question), but I really need Oracle-branded documentation with this for inclusion with the tech report on performance. Either that, or I develop test cases that prove beyond a shadow of a doubt what is or is not an issue.

Comment: @Thomas Owens this is common knowledge. It has been the case for fifteen years or more. You don't need test cases. You only need to compare some binaries to prove it.

Comment: @EJP Then show me the docs where this knowledge comes from. I would compare if I wasn't in the middle of profiling and crunching those numbers. It's a fairly simple idea - Oracle-branded documentation or I need to scientifically show that in non-trivial cases (most likely meaning for all class files produced for this system) this is a true statement. I veru much suspect it - it's in any writing on Java. But it's not formal enough without official docs or scientifically valid test cases.

Comment: @Thomas Owens it comes from my 14+ years of experience with Java. Binary comparison is also a 'fairly simple idea' and it is also 'scientifically valid'. Especially if you compared the compiler binaries. You seem fixated on creating unnecessary work.

Comment: @EJP I have two options. (1) Compare several hundred .class files between Windows and Solaris after compilation on each OS and assert that each one is identical, most likely through the creation of a script to automate the comparison. (2) Find Oracle documentation that says that given a particular version of the JDK, the output of `javac` is identical regardless of OS. Choose one of those. The `javac` compiler binaries are not the same on Windows and Solaris - they are even different sizes - so that's not useful to me.

Comment: @Thomas, You won't find documentation which says the compiler is; thread safe, works at midnight, or works if you are facing Mecca.  It doesn't make sense to suspect this is a problem so why document every possible thing people might worry about?

Comment: @Thomas: The actual compiler binary is tools.jar, not the executable which launches the VM.

Answer (score 1):

The compilation output should not depend on OS on which javac was called.
If you want to verify it try:

```
me@windows@ javac Main.java
me@windows@ javap Main.class > Main.win.txt

me@linux@ javac Main.java
me@linux@ javap Main.class > Main.lin.txt

diff Main.win.txt Main.lin.txt
```

Comment: It looks like manual verification is the only way to go. I could probably automate it, since I'm going to want to verify that hundreds of `.class` files are identical, but so far, no one has been able to produce Oracle-branded documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to google it anyway. ;)

http://java.sun.com/docs/white/platform/javaplatform.doc1.html

> The Java Platform is a new software platform for delivering and running highly interactive, dynamic, and secure applets and applications on networked computer systems. But what sets the Java Platform apart is that it sits on top of these other platforms, and executes bytecodes, which are not specific to any physical machine, but are machine instructions for a virtual machine. A program written in the Java Language compiles to a bytecode file that can run wherever the Java Platform is present, on any underlying operating system. In other words, the same exact file can run on any operating system that is running the Java Platform. This portability is possible because at the core of the Java Platform is the Java Virtual Machine.

Written April 30, 1996.

---

A common mistake, esp if you have developed for C/C++, is to assume that the compiler optimises the code.  It does one and only one optimisation which is to evaluate compiler time known constants.

It is certainly true that the compiler is no where near as powerful as you might imagine because it just validates the code and produces byte-code which matches your code as closely as possible.

This is because the byte-code is for an idealised virtual machine which in theory doesn't need any optimisations. Hopefully when you think about it that way it makes sense that the compiler does do anything much, it doesn't know how the code will actually be used.

Instead all the optimisation is performed by the JIT in the JVM.  This is entirely platform dependant and can produce 32-bit or 64-bit code and use the exact instruction of the processor running the code.  It will also optimise the code based on how it is actually used, something a static compiler cannot do. It means the code can be re-compiled more than once based on different usage patterns. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To extend on dacwe's part "Maybe the Solaris JVM is slower than the windows JVM?"

There are configuration options (e.g., whether to use the client or server vm [[link]](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html), and probably others as well), whose defaults differ depending on the OS. So that might be a reason why the Solaris VM is slower here.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding javac only consideres the `-target` argument to decide what bytecode to emit, hence there is no platform specific in the byte code generation.

All the optimization is done by the JVM, not the compiler, when interpreting the byte codes.  This is specific to the individual platform.

Also I've read somewhere that the Solaris JVM is the reference implementation, and then it is ported to Windows.  Hence the Windows version is more optimzied than the Solaris one.

Comment: That is my understanding as well, but I haven't come across any docs that explicitly say this. Having that in hand would save me a ton of time.

Comment: @Thomas, It is part of the the compile once, run anywhere mantra. If different OSes result in different byte code for even one byte, its a bug. You should be able to compare the actual byte code to see the differences or check the checksums of all the class (if you put them in a jar)

Comment: @Thomas, you could have a look at the compiler sources in the OpenJDK project to be certain.   The Eclipse compiler is also open source and can replace javac.

Answer (score 0):

> Does javac perform any bytecode level optimizations depending on the
>   underlying operating system?

No.

Determining why the performance characteristics of your program are different on two platforms requires profiling them under the same workload, and careful analysis of method execution times and memory allocation/gc behaivor.  Does your program do any I/O?

Comment: I'm in the process of profiling now. There's file reading, database connectivity, and logging to a file as well as to the console. The data sets in the test case are identical and in both cases are being read locally, which is why I'm surprised that a "more powerful" (or so I'm told - I still don't have the exact specs) server is getting destroyed in performance.

Comment: I/O complicates the picture - ALOT.  Are your databases both tuned?

Comment: I don't manage the database end. That's all on other people. I'm just trying to prove that it's not software that's causing the significant slowdown. Ratios of time spent overall appear to be consistent, based on my data, so it's looking like it's all coming down to tuning of the JVM and database to try to squeeze more performance out.